# Wireless display from one laptop to another

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, kvm

**Here is my setup**:

1. macbook pro retina physically connected to 2 external monitors, and keyboard+mouse.
2. 17 macbook on its own

**What I want to do**:

I'd like to somehow use one of the external monitors connected to laptop (1) to display the screen of laptop (2).

The idea is that I don't want to have to connect/disconnect anything.  I want to be able to, on demand, use 1 of the displays connected to (1) to display what is on (2) without physically adjusting cables.

Is this possible?  Bonus points if someone can suggest a software kvm style solution so that in addition to using the monitors connected to (1), I can also use the mouse + keyboard connected to (1) to drive (2)

Answer (score 2):

1. click "System preferences > sharing" and enable the screen sharing.
2. on screen sharing preferences copy the Adress that is like this "vnc://..." save to a txt file and send to the other computer through airdrop.
3. open safari on the other computer, paste the addres and press enter, the screen of the first computer will apear.

You don't need any software, doing this steps you will control bouth computers with 1 mouse and 1 keyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

- Install [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) on the Mac to receive the screen data over the network.
- Configure AirPlay to extend the sending Mac's screen.
- Wait for OS X Mavericks which will allow the remote screen to be a full screen with a Dock and full control rather than a mirror display that Mountain Lion allows.

Reverse this when you want to have a different keyboard and mouse to drive. IF you're OK with mirroring just the one remote screen to the local Mac with many screens, you might also be able to just use Remote Desktop ([Apple's version](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/), [Screens app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-control-your-computer/id446107677?mt=12), or other VNC control to bring the remote Mac's display to the local Mac).